# get order, customer, product details in observer magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, event-observer, customer

I am trying to get order,customer,product details in observer. I am using event **sales_order_save_after**.

```
<?php
namespace Gworks\Sms\Model\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class AfterPlaceOrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_logger;
    public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, //log injection
    array $data = []
    ) {
    $this->_logger = $logger;
       // parent::__construct($data);
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    { 
     //order id
     $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
     $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
     $this->_logger->info($order_id);

     //product id and name
     foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item)
     {
     $ProdustIds[]= $item->getProductId();
     $proName[] = $item->getName(); // product name
     }
     foreach($proName as $name)
     {
       $this->_logger->info($name);
     }
     foreach($ProdustIds as $id)
     {
       $this->_logger->info($id);
     }

     //customer id
     $customerid = $order->getCustomerId();
     $this->_logger->info($customerid);

     //customer name
     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customer);
     $name=$customer->getName();
     $this->_logger->info($name);
    } 
}
```

I need to get below details.

1. customer name
2. phone number
3. ordered product name
4. shipping address

I have to collect customer name and product name in **system.log** but I stuck with get shipping address and phone number in log.

Comment: try to catch **sales_order_place_after** event as the required detail may not be available in the observer at the event you are catching(sales_order_save_after), because all the data is already passed at sales_order_save_after event..

use **sales_order_place_after**..

Comment: ND17 answer is correct you can't get product details directly from `sales_order_place_after`, you can get by using `foreach()` function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't get product id like this `$observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId();`

This is order event not product event

```
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
 $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
 $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
 $this->_logger->info($order_id);   
 foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
      $ProdustIds[]= $item->getProductId();

     $proName[] = $item->getName(); // product name
 }
 $this->logger->info($ProdustIds);
 $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress(); // shipping address
 $customer = $order->getCustomerId(); // using this id you can get customer name
}
```

And for phone number you can get from shipping address or using customer id

Comment: thanks It partially works after some modification, I have updated my question.

Comment: all the details I have collected except shipping address, still my question alive if I tick its over :-)

Comment: Sorry i didn't notice that

Comment: in shipping address what is  problem?